# CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver

Tags: dbus, gnome-screensaver

I received this critical error in my logs, but I haven't had any problems so far. If anyone knows why I get this error and what it means, I'd really appreciate an answer from you.

```
CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug? Do you remember if Gnome crashed when the log arise? Please edit to add the output of `inxi -SMIG -! 31 && journalctl -b0 -p2 && grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/796qlo/ubuntu_1710_freezes_on_suspendwont_shut_down/dp032ah/) someone seems to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a known bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1736011
The only side effect I see mentioned is a delay in the login window propagating

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same critical message during my system boot. My system start-up was blocked: it was not possible to get the login screen.
My machine is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on an ASUS laptop. No need to reinstall the system to fix this issue.
As the problem is linked to the graphical interface Gnome and I faced some troubleshooting with gnome extensions after my last system upgrade, I focused on Gnome Shell extensions.

The fix for me comes from [jkapelus here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374885&p=13705192#post13705192):
In `/home/$USER/.local/share/gnome-shell/extenstions/`, run `rm -f -r` for each extension directory.

After a reboot, the login screen was recovered.