# Critical Error messages when booting , Automatic suspend not working

Tags: gnome, suspend, screensaver

```
CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
```

I am not sure if this has something to do with the problem ,I am running 18.04.
Thanks

Comment: Try this [method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297301/522064). Hope this will fix your pb.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I found a quick fix explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297301/522064)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
It turned out to be a defective mouse. It must of been telling the computer i was still using it.

Cheers